# su -c replacement using c++

Tags: c++, linux

We wanted to run a command not as a root user and we don't want use su -c, but would like to code in c++.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *argv[] = { "/bin/sh",  "abc.sh", 0 };
    char *envp[] =
    {
        "HOME=/",
        "PATH=/bin:/usr/bin",
        "TZ=UTC0",
        "USER=trishul",
        "LOGNAME=tarzan",
        0
    };
    execve(argv[0], &argv[0], envp);
    fprintf(stderr, "Oops!\n");
    return -1;
}

#abc.sh
pwd
date
```

I used chmod 700 abc.sh, not to allow user to execute my sample program.
When execute above code with root user, still i could able to see the output of pwd and date. 
The above behavior is happening because it's still executing as root I think.
Some how I need to make the sample to be executed with "trishul" using execve.

My whole intention is to deny permission to normal users except root, because the script what i write shall also have reboot. The user "trishul" should get permission denied

Could you help us in this regard.

Comment: I don't get it. Why would the root user not be able to determine the current directory or the current date? What specifically is happening that you don't want to happen?

Comment: Regardless of root or whatever user using `abc.sh`. The command `/bin/sh abc.sh` doesn't "execute" `abc.sh`, it execute `/bin/sh` which will *read* `abc.sh` and do what it is written in it. So making `abc.sh` non executable will not prevent anyone from using it (it will only disallow executing it directly by doing, for example, `./abc`). What you want is probably making the file non-readable.

Comment: that's the sample, the whole intention is to stop some user executing a script( apart from root)

Comment: Then it is the read permission you want to strip off, along with the execution permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just removing the execute permission will not do it: the command `/bin/sh abc.sh` doesn't "execute" `abc.sh`, it executes `/bin/sh` which will *read* `abc.sh` and do what is written in it (in other words, `/bin/sh` is executed und runs the commands it *reads* in `abc.sh`, `abc.sh` itself is not executed). Thus, making `abc.sh` non executable will not prevent anyone from using it (it will only disallow executing it directly by doing, for example, `./abc`).

If you want the file `abc.sh` only usable by root (which is suggested in the comments but **really** unclear in your question), just change it's owner to root, then disallow read and execution to other users (and probably write too):

```
chown root abc.sh # Make root the owner of the file
chmod 700 abc.sh  # Give the owner (root) every rights on the file and give none to others
```

Further understanding your question, you want to change your user ID to `trishul`'s one before the `execve`. Use [setuid() from `unistd.h` to change your user ID](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Setuid-Program-Example.html).

Comment: Okay,May I know what changes I have to made to execute the script directly? because the user "trishul" should get permission denied.

Comment: @Trishul If the user issues `./abc.sh`, he is executing it directly, if he issues `sh abc.sh` he's just executing `sh` by telling it to read `abc.sh`. If you want to disallow `./abc.sh`, remove the execute permission. If you want to disallow `sh abc.sh`, remove the read permission. (So if you want to disallow the user to use this file in every way, you have to remove the execute *and* read permission for that user)

Comment: When execute above code with root user, still i could able to see the output of pwd and date. The above behavior is happening because it's still executing as root I think. Some how I need to make the sample to be executed with "trishul" using execve.

Comment: @Trishul I edited my answer, you need to change your user ID before `execve`, see Basile's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to make your compiled executable a [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) one (using `chmod u+s`). Be very careful about that (so read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) first, and use appropriately [seteuid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/seteuid.2.html) and/or [setreuid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setreuid.2.html)...).

Don't make mistakes, otherwise you can open a very large security hole! See also [super(1)](http://www.linuxcertif.com/man/1/super/) command.

Read also about [restricted shell](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Restricted-Shell.html) in `bash`, you probably need to use it. Be aware that the shell needs to read its script!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you have a *nix application that you want to quit if it is not running as root.

The `getuid` function in unistd.h will return 0 if running as root:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
        if (getuid())
        {
                std::cout << "Not root" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
                std::cout << "Running as root!" << std::endl;
        }
}
```

So a simple check is

```
if (getuid())
  std::cout << "You but run this as root" << std::endl;
```

This works in linux (tested under Ubuntu).  It looks like standard POSIX but I can't confirm portability.